# Including entities in a groupBy clause of a CriteriaBuilder query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following hypothetical model:

```
@Entity
class Parent{

    Integer number;
    Child1 child1;
    Child2 child2;
    String description;
}

@Entity
class Child1{
    Integer id;
}

@Entity
class Child2{
    Integer id;
}
```

I am building a query that does an aggregation function over `number` in `Parent`, but I also want to display `child1` and `child2`, so I include them in my group by clause in criteria builder.  For some other random reason I am creating a `Tuple` query.

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Parent> root = cq.from(Parent.class);
cq.select(cb.tuple(root.get("description"),
                   root.get("child1")
                   cb.count(root.get("number")));

cq.groupBy(root.get("description"),
           root.get("child1")));
```

When I execute this query, I get the error: "child1.id is included in the SELECT but is not included in a group by clasue and is not part of an aggregate function".  Whenever I select fields from entity `Parent` that are not entities themselves, I have no trouble.  As soon as I try to select a field from class `Parent` that itself is an entity, then I run into that trouble, even if I include it in the group by clause.  I have even tried doing this without luck:

```
cq.groupBy(root.get("description"),
           root.get("child1").get("id")));
```

How can I create a `CriteriaQuery` that does what I want to do? Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

We have to use aggregate functions for all the fields in table except for the one on which group by is being performed.
So in your case, you can only select values from entities using following functions.

```
AVG() - Returns the average value.
COUNT() - Returns the number of rows.
FIRST() - Returns the first value.
LAST() - Returns the last value.
MAX() - Returns the largest value.
MIN() - Returns the smallest value.
SUM() - Returns the sum.
```

You can not groupby number and select child1 without aggregate function.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that you can group by more than one field.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas definitely we can groupby more than one field. Let say you groupby A,B,C then you can select A,B & C without aggregate functions but for rest of the fields you have to use aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it happen, apparently an explicit join is needed so that when the criteria query gets translated to JPA, the proper fields are recognized as present. The way I made it happen is the following:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Parent> root = cq.from(Parent.class);
Join<Parent, Child1> child1Join = root.join("child1");

cq.select(cb.tuple(root.get("description"),
                  child1Join.get("id"),
                  cb.count(root.get("number")));

cq.groupBy(root.get("description"),
           child1Join.get("id")));
```